# const parameter vs const reference parameter

Tags: c++, optimization, reference, constants, alias

Implementation 1:

```
foo(const Bar x);
```

Implementation 2:

```
foo(const Bar & x);
```

If the object will not be changed within the function, why would you ever copy it(implementation 1).

Will this be automatically optimized by the compiler?

**Summary**: Even though the object is declared as `const` in the function declaration, it is still possible that the object be edited via some other alias `&`.

If you are the person writing the library and know that your functions don't do that or that the object is big enough to justify the dereferencing cost on every operation, than 
`foo(const Bar & x);` is the way to go.

**Part 2**:

> Will this be automatically optimized by the compiler?

Since we established that they are not always equivalent, and the conditions for equivalence is non-trivial, it would generally be very hard for the compiler to ensure them, so *almost certainly* **no**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you ask,

> “If the object will not be changed within the function, why would you ever copy it(implementation 1).”

well there are some bizarre situations where an object passed by reference might be changed by other code, e.g.

```
namespace g { int x = 666; }

void bar( int ) { g::x = 0; }

int foo( int const& a ) { assert( a != 0 );  bar( a );  return 1000/a; }  // Oops

int main() { foo( g::x ); }
```

this has never happened to me though, since the mid 1990s.

so, this **aliasing** is a *theoretical problem* for the single argument of that type.

with two arguments of the same type it gets more of a real possibility. for example, an assignment operator might get passed the object that it's called on. when the argument is passed by value (as in the minimal form of the swap idiom) it's no problem, but if not then *self-assignment* generally needs to be avoided.

you further ask,

> “Will this be automatically optimized by the compiler?”

no, not in general, for the above mentioned reason

the compiler can generally not guarantee that there will be no aliasing for a reference argument (one exception, though, is where the machine code of a call is inlined)

however, on the third hand, the language *could* conceivably have supported the compiler in this, e.g. by providing the programmer with a way to explicitly accept any such optimization, like, a way to say ”this code is safe to optimize by replacing pass by value with pass by reference, go ahead as you please, compiler”

Comment: Things go bad regardless of
`int foo( int const& a )` or `int foo( int const a )`

Comment: @aiao: oh yes. thanks, sorry, i didn't notice (i also forgot the `main` the first time around). fixed.

Answer (score 5):

Indeed, in those circumstances you would normally use method 2.

Typically, you would only use method 1 if the object is tiny, so that it's cheaper to copy it once than to pay to access it repeatedly through a reference (which also incurs a cost). In [TC++PL](http://www.amazon.co.uk/C-Programming-Language-Special/dp/0201700735), Stroustrup develops a complex number class and passes it around by value for exactly this reason.

Comment: Performance is one reason, but I'd say correctness is a bigger deal. And the correctness of your code may depend on a copy being created.

Answer (score 2):

It may be optimized in some circumstances, but there are plenty of things that can prevent it. The compiler can't avoid the copy if:

- the copy constructor or destructor has side effects and the argument passed is not a temporary.
- you take the address of `x`, or a reference to it, and pass it to some code that might be able to compare it against the address of the original.
- the object might change while `foo` is running, for example because `foo` calls some *other* function that changes it. I'm not sure whether this is something you mean to rule out by saying "the object will not be changed *within* the function", but if not then it's in play.

You'd copy it if any of those things matters to your program:

- if you want the side effects of copying, take a copy
- if you want "your" object to have a different address from the user-supplied argument, take a copy
- if you don't want to see changes made to the original during the running of your function, take a copy

You'd also copy it if you think a copy would be more efficient, which is generally assumed to be the case for "small" types like `int`. Iterators and predicates in standard algorithms are also taken by value.

Finally, if your code plans to copy the object anyway (including by assigning to an existing object) then a reasonable idiom is to take the copy as the parameter in the first place. Then move/swap from your parameter.

Answer (score 1):

What if the object is changed from elsewhere?

```
void f(const SomeType& s);
void g(const SomeType s);

int main() {
    SomeType s;

    std::thread([&](){ /* s is non-const here, and we can modify it */}

    // we get a const reference to the object which we see as const, 
    // but others might not. So they can modify it.
    f(s);

    // we get a const *copy* of the object, 
    // so what anyone else might do to the original doesn't matter 
    g(s);
}
```

What if the object is const, but has mutable members? Then you can still modify the object, and so it's very important whether you have a copy or a reference to the original.

What if the object contains a pointer to another object? If `s` is const, the pointer will be const, but what it *points to* is not affected by the constness of `s`. But creating a copy will (hopefully) give us a deep copy, so we get our own (const) object with a separate (const) pointer pointing to a separate (non-const) object.

There are a number of cases where a const copy is different than a const reference.

Comment: "Then you can still modify the object" -- it may be that the questioner is trying to rule that out by saying, "if the object will not be changed in the function". But you might be right, the questioner might wrongly believe that an object passed by const reference can't be changed, and means "the object will not be changed, so why copy it?"

Comment: @Steve: consider whether the question is at all meaningful (would be something the OP could want to have clarified) under your interpretation.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: yes, it is meaningful and it could be clarified. There are several other potential reasons to take the copy than because the original changes its value, so ruling that out still leaves a question of substance. However, since the questioner accepted your answer I can now conclude that those other reasons are not of interest :-)

Comment: +1 because it remained at 0 votes and really deserved some upvotes, since readers interested in the question have little else to go on to evaluate answers.